# Which merge layers to use in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

Keras has many different ways of merging inputs like `Add()`, `Subtract()`, `Multiply()`, `concatenate()`, etc...

Do they all have the same effect or are there situations where one is preferable?

Comment: They all do different things, it all depends on the specific problem and application.

Comment: could you give a example of a situation where one layer is preferable and why? It would help me tremendously. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you got anything on this? I'm looking for the same part

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve but briefly let's look at different merge layers and what they are often used for:

- **add** Addition is a common merge operation for networks that use relu activation function as the sum will also be positive and can encode an OR operation. For example, you want to identify if any of the comments for this answer are positive using a deep network, then you can add all the encoded representations.
- **subtract** Subtraction in conjunction with squaring so (x-y)^2 is used for equality relationships, how *close* is something to another. These pop up in attention calculations, does this region in the image contain features I'm looking for could be a subtraction.
- **multiply** Similar to subtraction, if you have features say from a tanh, then you can multiply them element wise to find similar features. If both are positive or negative the multiplication will be positive negative otherwise, the networks use this information well.
- **average** is often traded for concatenate not to lose information but if the problem mathematically makes sense to have each previous branch of computation to have equal weight then you average. For example, you might want to find the overall sentiment of a paragraph and don't want any single negative sentence to affect a neutral paragraph.
- **maximum** pop up in pooling operations like [MaxPooling](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) and allow you to achieve some invariance over the dimension. In images it doesn't matter where the cat is to classify for cat, similarly it doesn't matter where the anomaly occurs if you just want to detect it.
- **concatenate** is the most common because it lets the upstream network to decide how to use the given information. It is used to gather information and often outputs of other merge layers. So you can compute multiplication and merge with its inputs `[x, y, x*y]`. By default it is used in [Bidirectional](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#bidirectional) to let information from both directions.

Answer (score 1):

Merge layers performs the operation selected. For detail keras documentations: https://keras.io/layers/merge/.
Add: Adds list of inputs, tensors in case of Keras Model.
Multiply: Element-wise multiplication of a list of inputs.
and so on.

Therefore, select according to your application. The effect would be different, for scientific comments please go through:

- ResNet (uses addition) https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385
- UNET (uses concatenation)https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597.

In you are from CV background, this paper would give you more insights: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06612.pdf